# Xournal toolbar abnormally scaled

Tags: 16.04, menu, notes

I was taking notes during a class, when I suddenly got distracted, and the moment after this is what presented itself to my astonished self. The very same window, but with the toolbar abnormally scaled.
EDIT: I am not sure about it, but I don't exclude having pressed some key. The only thing that had changed when looking back at the screen was the toolbar.
I tried purging and reinstalling Xournal, but the toolbar remains like this. (yes, the big white square that looks like a paper sheet is actually the colour picker)
Could anybody help me revert it?
Thanks

[image: xournal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are being bitten by this bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/xournal/bugs/164/

As a developer feature, xournal loads its graphic resources from the directory where the command is located, if it is not the standard path (most likely `/usr/bin/xournal`).

I can only guess here because I don't know from where you are starting xournal, but is it possible that in that directory you have a file named `white.png` or something like this? If so: try running xournal as `/usr/bin/xournal` and/or remove that png file.

Comment: Would you believe it? I had made that white.png file myself for covering a piece of picture I had imported in my notes within Xournal itself. Thank you very much for the careful job of finding my exact case